# Слово класс в аргументе функции

Tags: c++

Первый раз встретил данную конструкцию, когда `class` в параметрах функции и не могу понять для чего оно используется?

`virtual void SetupInputComponent(class UInputComponent* InputComponent) override;`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Эта штука (`{class|struct|union|enum} имя`) называется [*elaborated type specifier*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier).

Между `UInputComponent` и `class UInputComponent` почти нет разницы.

---

**1.** Естественно, если справа от `class` написать не класс, а другой тип - это ошибка.

**2.** Если `UInputComponent` еще не был объявлен, то `class UInputComponent` не вызывает ошибку, а объявляет класс в текущем `namespace` (даже если мы внутри класса, объявляется все равно не в нем, а в самом вложенном `namespace`).

Это работает только если имя *неквалифицированное* (не содержит `::`). Если оно квалифицированное и такой класс еще не был объявлен - это ошибка.

**3.** Elaborated type specifier нужен когда название класса совпадает с названием еще чего-то:

```
class A {};

void foo()
{
    int A;

    A ptr; // error: must use 'class' tag to refer to type 'A' in this scope
    class A ptr; // ok
}
```

**4.** Elaborated type specifier убирает необходимость в `typename` в шаблонах:

```
struct A
{
    class B{};
};

template <typename T = A> struct C
{
    T::B y; // error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'T::B'
    typename T::B x; // ok
    class T::B y; // ok
};

C c;
```

Но `typename` работает для всех типов, а `class` - только для классов. Не стоит путать elaborated type specifier с объявлением шаблонных параметров: между `template <typename T>` и `template <class T>` разницы нет.

Comment: В последнем случае не убирает необходимость, а используется как синоним. Тогда можно вспомнить и о `template<class T>...`

Comment: @Harry Не совсем синоним. Если тип - не класс, `class` вызывает ошибку.

Comment: нет такого, они всегда взоимозаменяемые ключевые слова(начиная с С++11 (или 14 _ точно не помню)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan В `template <...>` - да, но я не про это: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/gMSTfP

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, если вы имеете ввиду, что к встроенным типам не применимо `class`, то кажется ваш последный  случай  не очень понятно изложен, или  просто я не так понел. В любом случаи ответ хороший, но  я бы сказал, что в общем случаи  ключевое слово `class`  обозначает, что следующий за ним индентификатор является именем  не встроенного типа_ думаю этого достаточно.

Comment: ....если речь не о параметрах шаблона

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Добавил небольшое уточнение.

Comment: ОК, я увидел и уже проголосовал